# How to check whether a shell command returned nothing or something

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a script to extract something from a specified path. I am returning those values into a variable. How can i check whether the shell command has returned something or nothing.

My Code:

```
def any_HE():
    global config, logger, status, file_size
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config2.cfg')
    for section in sorted(config.sections(), key=str.lower):
        components = dict() #start with empty dictionary for each section
    #Retrieving the username and password from config for each section
        if not config.has_option(section, 'server.user_name'):
            continue
        env.user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
        env.password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
        host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
        print "Trying to connect to {} server.....".format(section)

        with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),warn_only=True, host_string=host):
            try:
                files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
                if files!=0:
                    print '{}--Something'.format(section)
                else:
                    print '{} --Nothing'.format(section)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
```

I tried checking 1 or 0 and True or false but nothing seems to be working. In some servers, the path '/opt/nds/' does not exist. So in that case, nothing will be there on files. I wanted to differentiate between something returned to files and nothing returned to files.

Comment: What exactly is `run`?

Comment: You need to use the `subprocess` module to manage your process. Look at the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Your indention is broken, this code will never run.

Comment: tichodroma.. it was a copy paste error. Correcting in the main.

Comment: is it `run` in `fabric` module or what ?

Comment: furas.. Yes, its fabric. I will attach the full code in the main

Comment: You should write it in question - nobody can read in your mind.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

Comment: Furas.. Sorry for that. I have put the full function in the main

Comment: You should put information that you use `fabric` - it is more important. Not everyone use `fabric` and can recognize `run` command.

Comment: try `print(files, type(files))` and you see what you get.

Comment: furas.. Print files will show all the full /opt/nds/ structure. type will give <class 'fabric.operations._AttributeString'>

Comment: You should just use built-in Python tools to get a directory listing…

Answer (score 2):

First, you're hiding `stdout`.
If you get rid of that you'll get a string with the outcome of the command on the remote host. You can then split it by `os.linesep` (assuming same platform), but you should also take care of other things like SSH banners and colours from the retrieved outcome.

Answer (score 1):

[`plumbum`](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a great library for running shell commands from a python script. E.g.:

```
from plumbum.local import ls
from plumbum import ProcessExecutionError
cmd = ls['-ltr']['/opt/nds']  # construct the command
try:    
    files = cmd().splitlines()  # run the command
    if ...:
        print ...:
except ProcessExecutionError:
    # command exited with a non-zero status code
    ...
```

On top of this basic usage (and unlike the `subprocess` module), it also supports things like output redirection and command pipelining, and more, with easy, intuitive syntax (by overloading python operators, such as '|' for piping).

Answer (score 1):

As perror commented already, the python subprocess module offers the right tools.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

For your specific problem you can use the check_output function.
The documentation gives the following example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
```

gives "Hello World"

Comment: A.L.  ... Is there any other way to check whether anything has been returned. I dont want to change the code now as so many functions are there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more control of the process you run, you need to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Here is an example of code:

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-ltr', '/opt/nds'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print task.communicate()
```